# Conda override dependency resolution for package

Tags: python, conda

I have a conda environment that I want to save to an environment.yaml to be able to install on spin-up cloud instances. The problem is that pip chokes on version mismatches on packages I do not control. But I rely on a fix not present in the resolved dependency and to this package from the other is too tight, but I can't loosen up the bound on the package I do not control. Is there any way I can override the version of a specific dependency? It just has to ignore the mismatch on a single dependency and blindly install it.

Comment: Not such functionality. And definitely not going to get this automated through a Conda YAML. Seems like a container (e.g., Docker) would be better solution here (i.e., work out all the kinks in the image and just deploy).

Comment: yeah, i thought so. It just makes everything more complex...

Comment: I have the same issue.